# Simple way to display results of a sql query using web.py

Tags: python, web-frameworks, web.py

Using web.py, I'm creating a handful of result sets by using

```
web.database.query()
```

And I'd like to display the query results on an html template.

Does web.py have any built-in facility for doing this? I didn't see any going through the doc and code samples.

I'd also appreciate any pointers to other modules that will coerce the sql result set into something that can be displayed by a jquery or google data grid. I started working on a google data grid converter but I had to jump through some hoops to handle the various datatypes. I figure this has been done tons of times before - I'd just like to know where I should be looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the docs for [web.py's built-in templating system](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor).  There are also [cookbook examples for hooking in 3rd party template engines](http://webpy.org/cookbook/) like [Mako](http://webpy.org/cookbook/template_mako), [Cheetah](http://webpy.org/cookbook/template_cheetah) and [Jinja2](http://webpy.org/cookbook/template_jinja).

In order to convert the data to be displayed by Javascript you could use one of the JSON modules for Python: [the standard json module (2.6+)](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson), or [python-cjson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-cjson).

Here is a quick example of using the `web.template` module to render a simple HTML page showing some database query results.

**Updated** The `select` method doesn't return the column names as a separate attribute. It returns an iterator where each row is a dictionary. Therefore, to get the column headers you need to grab then from the first row.  I've updated the example to show how this can be done:

```
import web

TEMPLATE = '''$def with (rows, cols)
<html><body>
<h2>Results:</h2>
<table>
<tr>
$for col in cols:
    <th>$col</th>
</tr>
$for row in rows:
    <tr>
    $for col in cols:
        <td>$row[col]</td>
    </tr>
</table></body></html>'''

class query:
    def GET(self, arg):
        res = db.select('player', what='id,name')
        cols = []
        rows = res.list()
        if rows:
            cols = rows[0].keys()
        return tmpl(rows, cols)

db = web.database(dbn='mysql')
tmpl = web.template.Template(TEMPLATE)
urls = ('/(.*)', 'query')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Output (collapsed to save space):

```
<html><body>
<h2>Results:</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>id</th><th>name</th></tr> 
<tr><td>1</td> <td>Joe</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Gary</td></tr>
<tr> <td>3</td><td>Fred</td></tr>
</table></body></html>
```

Comment: That's similar to what I've been doing. However, I've been trying to do something a little more in-depth. Since the rows object also has column headers, how can I include them in the table header? I can't figure out how to reference the names of the columns.

Comment: @Neil I updated my answer. In the version I'm using (latest `0.35`) the column headings must be retrieved from the first row, since the result is basically an iterator over dictionaries and doesn't have a separate column descriptor attribute.